# Does the message body go in the payload of the JWT?

Tags: jwt

I understand JWT is susceptible to replay attacks and according to a number blogs, the same token can be used by different servers and doesn't need to be regenerated.   Does that mean the JWT is not generated with the body of the message in the payload? To be secure, I thought it would be used to sign each request but then I guess is not very efficient and a new JWT needs to be generated per message?  I am a little confused. Would appreciate if someone could clarify this point.  Seems unsafe if someone could steal the JWT, change the message body and reuse the same authorisation header.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the body goes in the payload. A full JWT has a header, payload and signature. The signature ensures that the payload hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: OH, Thankfully that is true! Cheers! I was reading jwt.io and it wasn't clear to me that I could that message body goes in the payload as JWT is supposed to be small and short..

Comment: @Zera I'm afraid you might have misunderstood the question. If I understand the OP correctly, the question is about the request body and JWT as a means to sign the request. That's certainly not the 'normal' way of using JWTs. Ususally you use JWT as an access token and pass it int the authotization header and it only  contains information relevant for authorization, but no request data.

Comment: @jps I may have misunderstood the question as it was a bit unclear. If you have anything else to share then I encourage you to do so.

Comment: Hi @jps Yes that is correct. I see. So essentially, I am just passing around the same level of authority as username as password.  I am familiar with signing requests and I thought JWT is just the same (stick in my message in to payload, sign it, to produce a hash that goe with message to prove it has not been tampered with,

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @jps I am guessing it's not normal to do it that way but there is no stopping me from doing it - it's rather inefficient and not what JWT was really meant for? Cheers

Comment: Right, there's nothing that stops you doing it. The [JWT RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519) says: "JSON Web Token (JWT) is a compact, URL-safe means of representing  claims to be transferred between two parties. The claims in a JWT are encoded as a JSON object that is used as the payload of a JSON Web Signature (JWS) structure or as the plaintext of a JSON Web Encryption (JWE) structure, enabling the claims to be digitally signed or integrity protected with a Message Authentication Code (MAC) and/or encrypted."     Authentication/Authorization is just the most common use for it

Comment: but technicaly there is no reason not to use it to transfer whatever kind of data with a signature.